# External content type from SQL stored procedure with EXEC

Tags: 2010, list, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, content-type

I'm trying to create an external content type from a stored procedure. I'm hitting one problem, when creating a **Read List Operation**, though:

The wizard is not able to find any **return parameters** (see image), when my stored procedure ends with `EXEC`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getData
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR ( MAX);
  EXEC @sql;
END
```

Now, if I use a common select, SharePoint is able to recognize return parameters:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getData
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM data_table;
END
```

**I need to use EXEC**, as I use a lot of metadata in my procedure. Is this a limitation of Sharepoint? Can I get a workaround?

[image: Return parameter]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, you could save the results of the EXEC into a table, and return that:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getData
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR ( MAX);
  DECLARE @table TABLE (
    field1 INT, ...
  );

  INSERT INTO @table (field1, ... )
    EXEC @sql;

  SELECT * FROM @table;
END
```